# Wireshark can not filter protocol IPv4

Tags: wireshark

I have a list of packages:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

I input `cldap`, I can filter out all the protocol packages:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

If I input the `IPv4`: I can not filter out what should appear:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Comment: Easiest thing to do is find what you want to filter on in the lower pane. ip v6 = 0x86DD so `eth.type == 0x86dd`, ip v4 = 0x0800 so `eth.type == 0x0800` https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EtherType. You can also use just `ip` for ipv4 and `ipv6` for ip v6. Otherwise go to Statistics - Protocol Hierarchy and filter from there.

Comment: You have obscured the addresses, but it looks as if all your entries are IPv4. You can use `ip.proto==` or `ip.proto!=` to filter the entries you want. there is an explicit constant `IPv6`, but none for `IPv4`.

Comment: @HelpingHand Use the `ip` for filtering also gets the CLDAP. and use the same as `eth.type == 0x0800`.

Comment: @aircraft, but `cldap` would show up with an `ip` filter as it's UDP.  If you want `ip` traffic without `cldap` you could do `ip and !cldap`. I guess I'm not 100% sure what you're after exactly.